# What are Bruce Banner's Ph.Ds in the MCU?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok* Bruce Banner says that he holds 7 Ph.Ds.

What are the streams or fields in which Dr. Banner holds these degrees?

Basically, what are his qualifications in the MCU?

Comment: Since there is a close vote on this, we have similar questions over on SFF.
 [What are Bruce Banner's Ph.Ds?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176884/5184) [What are the educational qualifications of Bruce Banner in the movie The Incredible Hulk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86284/5184) [Does Banner have a medical degree?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31797/5184)

Comment: Why is there a close vote on this?   How is this trivia?  Attention close voter(s):  We need to stop nitpicking questions and stop slapping close votes on questions like this or we are not going to have any questions left on this site!

Comment: what's the point of getting more than two such degrees? MD/PHD makes sense but why does someone spend the time on more than that? i will bet no one in the world has more than. say, 3 phds from real universities.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I explained in my [answer to a similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176884/what-are-bruce-banners-ph-ds/176889#176889), we don't know precisely what 7 doctorates Banner holds. However, based on comments from colleagues, friends, and those who have hired him, we know he's at least an expert in the following fields:

- Radiophysics - the study of radiation and radioactivity. Fury claims he recruited Banner for his knowledge of gamma radiation.
- Biochemistry - the study of the chemistry of living tissue. Stark needed Banner's help to merge JARVIS into an organic host.
- Nuclear Physics - the study of sub-atomic particle interactions. In Avengers, Stark commented on Banner's research work in "anti-electron collisions".

He taught classes at Culver university in the first two, I believe, which means he would need a doctorate in those to qualify.

He's also generally regarded as "one of the smartest people alive", which in the Marvel continuity is a rather well-defined list of people (Tony Stark, Bruce Banner, Victor Von Doom, Reed Richards being the big 4 from the comics).

Comment: He may have something related to computer sciences and mathematics considering his abilities in such when finding the scepter and help building ultron and veronica

Comment: You do not need a doctorate in the subject to teach it at a US university. As a holder of an accredited CS degree, I believe a whopping 3 of my undergraduate instructors actually held CS doctorates themselves. Several were graduate students (and likely have doctorates now), and several others were professors with doctorates in related fields like Math or Electrical Engineering.

Comment: @kutulumike did Avengers: Endgame reveal some more of his capabilities

Comment: Don't forget Rocket /s

The Russos recently referred to him as being on of the cleverest in the universe

Comment: @GordonBennett don't forget about Shuri.
> Joe Russo declares Shuri the smartest character in the MCU

Comment: @TinyDoowy Normally yes, at the time they're talking about she'd only be useful if you needed to grit your driveway